# CommandNotFoundException in asp.net mvc 5 database migration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I tried to run this command:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextType ApplicationDbContext
```

And getting this exception:

```
Enable-Migrations : The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-Migrations -ContextType ApplicationDbContext
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am using vs 2015 community edition. Restarting and run it as administrator could not solve the issue. And if I try to run this command to reinstall Entity Framework:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease
```

Getting this exception as well:

```
Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' from source 'C:\Path\packages'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Please, Give me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

its case sensitive type

```
enable-migrations -contexttypename DBCONTEXT
```

you can also see the available options from

```
get-help EntityFramework
```

Comment: It didn't solve the issue. Same error is showing @Rahul